# How to resize a RealSense::Image

Tags: c++, intel, realsense

I have a `RealSense::Image` and I want to resize it. I cannot understand from the documentation how to.

I'm coding in C++:

```
Status result = pSenseManager->AcquireFrame(true);
Intel::RealSense::Image* segmented_image = pSeg->AcquireSegmentedImage();
```

for example `segmented_image` has now a size of 640x480 pixel. I want to resize it. What function should I invoke?

Comment: Convert it to OpenCV image and resize there.

Answer (score 1):

which RealSense camera do you use? R200, LR200, ZR300, SR300, D400 series?

- **For SR300 and D400 series**, suggest to use the new Intel SDK 2.0 librealsense which supports the cross-platform development. Now, the latest version is 2.7.9.

  example code:

  ```
  rs2::pipeline pipe;
  pipe.enable_stream(rs2_stream::RS2_STREAM_DEPTH, 0, 640, 480, rs2_format::RS2_FORMAT_Z16, FPS);
  ```
- **For R200, LR200 and ZR300**, you can use legacy librealsense (master)

  example code:

  ```
  dev->enable_stream(rs::stream::depth, 640, 480, rs::format::z16, 30);
  ```

You can find more detail in the librealsense samples and documents.